# Looking to set up Debian 9 and Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: 18.04, debian

I'm setting up to run something that requires "Linux Debian 9 and Ubuntu 18.04 LTS"
I'm a first time Linux user. I just set up a computer to run it with a fresh HDD.

I'm able to find a DVD for 18.04 on Ebay but I'm not sure what Debian 9 is. Can I buy any version of 18.04 and then download and run Debian 9? Or are all versions of Debians on there? Is Debian a "distribution"? I watched a video talking about distributions, but am not sure what it is.

Basically my question is : can I install the 18.04 I have as a first step and then work on figuring out Debian 9? Or do I have to acquire 18.04 and Debian 9 at the same time ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu) I am sorry but the Debian part is off-topic on [ubuntu.se]. And the mentioned Linux distributions are free of charge, you don’t need to _buy_ them.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with running Debian and Ubuntu on the same computer, but I've never heard of any software that actually *required* this. I can't know for sure without knowing the details, but I strongly suspect that what it meant by "Debian 9 and Ubuntu 18.04 LTS" was that those are the two operating systems it supports, i.e., that it meant to say "Debian 8 *or* Ubuntu 18.04 LTS."

Answer (score 0):

Debian is a GNU/Linux distribution '*upstream*' of Ubuntu. The current 'stable' release is debian 10, so debian 9 is an older release referred to as debian old-stable.

Debian can be downloaded at https://www.debian.org/distrib/

Ubuntu can be downloaded at https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop , it's releases are easier to understand, as they have a *yy.mm* format so 18.04 means the 2018-April release of Ubuntu.

Some releases (eg. Ubuntu Core 18) do use a *yy* release format, by they are specialist (for example Ubuntu Core is intended for IoT appliances/devices)

Ubuntu also have many 'flavors' (the same base system but with different desktops, the desktop is the GUI interface).  They can be downloaded at https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours